# c# non-linear stochastic optimization

Tags: c#, constraints, nonlinear-optimization, stochastic

I'm currently in search for a library capable of resolving a constrained non-linear optimization of 15 variables. I'm looking for a stochastic method because I'm looking for a global minimum and I have no initial guess.
Do ou guys know an library that might help me? Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic for stackoverflow because it is asking to recommend a [*a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource.*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251134/where-can-i-ask-about-finding-a-tool-library-or-favorite-off-site-resource)    This might be on-topic for https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com (though I'm not sure).

Comment: try posting your questions at [maths](https://math.stackexchange.com/) and maybe go through [these search results](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=stochastic+optimization) from there.

Comment: There exist also deterministic algorithms that do global optimization, such as [Baron](http://archimedes.cheme.cmu.edu/?q=baron),  [Couenne](https://projects.coin-or.org/Couenne) and [Antigone](http://helios.princeton.edu/ANTIGONE/).